# Checkable checkbox column in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to create an column of checkable boxes in sheets, 1 for each row. I have placed an array formula in A2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"","☐"))
```

However although this produces the correct number of boxes in the column, they are not able to be checked/unchecked individually . How can I get this working?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117456/add-a-checkbox-with-a-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- highlight the range
- insert checkboxes

[image]

- highlight the range
- go to conditional formatting
- add custom formula for **A1:A** range **`=IF(NOT(LEN(B1:B)), 1)`**
- select white background
- select **custom** color for font: **`#fffffd`**

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make a checkbox appear only if the cell to its right contains text?

Comment: in your case range for custom formula will be B2:B and applied for A2:A